# Could the Infinity Gauntlet be used to make two people fall in love with each other?

Tags: marvel, infinity-stones

I am wondering if there is anything in Marvel comic book canon or in the MCU that says that the Infinity Gauntlet has the power to make someone fall in love with the person wearing the Infinity Gauntlet, or that the wearer of the Infinity Gauntlet can use the Infinity Gauntlet to make two strangers fall in love with each other?

Perhaps the combined power of the Mind Stone and the Soul Stone would make two people fall in love.

Comment: The Mind Stone on its own can utterly control someone's mind. You wouldn't need the whole set..

Comment: @Valorum, that's true, yet it could also be argued that if you can control someone's soul with the Soul Stone then you probably can make the soul in one person fall in love with a soul within another person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [*Thanos Quest* #2](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/11449/thanos_quest_1990_2), the titular character acknowledges that he could force Death to love him (with the power of the Infinity Gauntlet) but that it would be a *hollow kind of love*.

[image: Panel 1: Thanos walks off to the left away from Death sat on her bone throne all the way at the right, in between them one of Death's minions stands by her side and a creature in a pool of blood. Panel 2: View up on Thanos' chest and face as he walks off thinking "I could force her to speak directly to me. I have the power to bend even her to me will. But what good would that do?" Panel 3: View from behind Thanos as he walks down a long tall torch lit corridor, he continues thinking "That's not the way I wanted it to be." Panel 4: View looking up at Thanos who has entered a doorway, thinking: "I desire her love, not her blind subservience. How could I have miscalculated so badly?"]

If he could influence the mind of as powerful a being as Death, **two humans should present little or no difficulty whatsoever, even just with the Mind Stone, not even the whole complement of gems.**